# Swagger: set type definition of @ApiModelProperty#datatype for java.util.Map

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm generating my swagger spec using springfox.

I have this `Object` property, I want to represent this with the type of `Map<String, String>` when I use `openapi-generator`.

```
@ApiModelProperty(
  dataType = "java.util.Map"
)
private Object dummy;
```

When the spec is generated, the output is:

```
"dummy": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
     "type": "object"
  }
}
```

with the spec above, the generated property will be `Map<String, Object>`.

What I want to achieve is to have an output like this:

```
"dummy": {
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": {
     "type": "string"
  }
}
```

Is this possible? I'm trying to look on how to set the type of `Map#value` but I can't seem to find one.

Thanks!

Comment: How is `ComplexObject` defined?

Comment: @Helen I think my definition for `ComplexObject` shouldn't matter.  I will change it to `Object` because  I simply want to represent is a `Map<String, String>` with the use of `@ApiModelProperty#datatype`. Unless there's no way and the definition of an object is what defines the type in `additionalProperties`